# XSLT 2.0 Convert a space separated string to a sequence

Tags: xslt

I'm looking for a function or simple method to convert a space-separated string into a sequence of strings. For example the string 'abcd ef ghi' would be converted to a three-string sequence: 'abcd','ef','ghi'. It can be assumed that there is only one space between the sets of characters. A string with no spaces would generate a one-string sequence.

I looked around through the usual references, but nothing jumped out at me. I'm using XSLT 2.0. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the [tokenize()](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/REC-xpath-functions-20101214/#func-tokenize) function.